# standard fancybox deployment on rails 3.0.3 - fancybox_buttons.png not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I have deployed fancybox v2.0.4 on my RoR v3.0.3 web app to create a photo gallery. I've been able to get fancy box to product a large image when a thumbnail is clicked, but am having several issues with the appearance and behavior not working as expected.

1st issue - I can't seem to get the fancybox buttons to appear. I've gone into the jquery.fancybox-buttons.css and changed the paths for the various "background-image: url" to point to the fancybox folder in the public/images folder (standard RoR). Here is an example:

```
background-image: url('./images/fancybox/fancybox_buttons.png');
```

My first suspicion is that I am referencing this incorrectly, but I've tried every relative path iteration I can think of.

2nd issue - The default div that shows fancybox image keeps getting tucked behind the div that has the image_tags in it. I have changed the z-index in the fancybox css files to be greater than the z-index in the other divs on the page. I can't seem to change this at all. Here is the default fancybox div I am referring to:

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-default fancybox-opened" style="display: block;     overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; height: auto; width: 486px; position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 468px; ">....</div>
```

3rd issue - I am unable to get any of the drop shadows or other "stock" css effects to appear. I have checked that the source code is pointing to the appropriate css files. I have placed all the fancybox css files in the standard RoR stylesheets folder and all the .js files in the standard javascript folder. In my Application.html.erb file I have explicitly called for these javascript libraries and stylesheets inside my  tags.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problems that were preventing this from working:

1. The path for the fancybox_sprite.png and all the other urls in the jquery.fancybox.css file need to be as follows (assuming you are placing the images in the default "public/images" folder in a standard RoR application:

   background-image: url('/images/fancybox_sprite.png');
2. I had conflicting jquery-.min.js files in the javascripts folder.

Case closed.